# ClearContent of unprotectedRanges automatic

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet and I want to delete the content of several unprotected ranges.
That is, I want the script to obtain the unprotected cells and then delete the content.
this is what i have so far:

```
function borrarnoprotegidos() {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('mysheet')
   var protection = sheet.protect();
   var unprotected = protection.getUnprotectedRanges();
Logger.log(unprotected)

 }
```

When doing logger.log I get:  Información   [Range, Range, Range, Range, Range] , which is the number of protected ranges. But I don't know how to delete the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function borrarnoprotegidos() {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('mysheet')
   var protection = sheet.protect();
   var unprotected = protection.getUnprotectedRanges();
   unprotected.forEach(r => r.clearContent());
 }
```

[range.clearContent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearContent())

Comment: Thank you very much, I have asked this on many websites and could not find the answer.